# Google Tagmanager Javascript Variable returns 'undefined' while console.log has data

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a variable in GTM, which listens to specific form option changes and returns (or should return) a string with all selected options.

I see the correct data in the console from console.log, but the variable value is 'undefined' in GTM preview mode. I do not understand why the variable is 'undefined', since I declare an empty string, so at least it should always return an empty string value and not undefined.

```
function(){
  var stringFacetValues = '';
  var arrayFacetValues = [];
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('form[class="wizard-facets"] select[class^="form-select"]');
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("change", function() {
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
      
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        arrayFacetValues.push(checkboxes[i].innerHTML);
      }
      stringFacetValues = arrayFacetValues.toString();
      console.log(stringFacetValues);
      return stringFacetValues;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You are returning the string to the event listener, which doesn't do anything. It isn't clear to me how the data is supposed to be returned or given to GTM.

Answer (score 1):

It's either a timing issue or a CSP issue in 99% of cases.

Timing: make sure it really has stuff to return exactly at the point where you trigger it.

CSP: make sure unsafe-eval is allowed. GTM can work without unsafe-eval, but then all CJS vars will return undefined always.

You can actually bypass unsafe-eval and still be able to execute custom JS in GTM, but via GTM's templates and they're not as simple to work with as CJS. There's also always an option to do that via CHTML tags, but those would be leveraging unsafe-inline. And they will pollute the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the variable to a custom html tag, which pushes the values to a dataLayer variable.

I use the values upon submit of the form, so timing is not an issue